# Monotonicity of the convolution residual in L^2

Tags: integration, analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

Consider an approximation of unity $(\phi_\epsilon)_\epsilon $ defined such that :

- $\forall \epsilon > 0, \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\phi_{\epsilon}(x)| dx = 1$
- $\forall R>0, \quad \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{||x || > R} |\phi_\epsilon(x)| dx = 0$
- $ \forall f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n), \quad \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} || f - \phi_\epsilon * f ||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} = 0.$

In the sequel, we assume that this family is constructed using a single function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via the definition: 
\begin{equation}
\phi_\epsilon = \epsilon^{-n}\phi(\cdot/\epsilon), \quad \quad (*)
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is integrable with $L^1$ integral equal to $1$.

Let $f$ be a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, define the mapping
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lcll}
 \Psi_{f,\Omega} \colon & \mathbb{R}^+ & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R}^+ \\
              & \epsilon & \longmapsto     & ||f - \phi_{\epsilon}*f||_{L^2(\Omega)}^2
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Aim: How to ensure the monotonicity of the mapping $\Psi_{f,\Omega}$ (at least in a neighbourhood of 0)? That is, what are the sufficient conditions on the function $\phi$ to guarantee that 
$$
\forall \epsilon_1 < \epsilon_2 \ll 1, \quad 
 \Psi_{f,\Omega}(\epsilon_1) \leq \Psi_{f,\Omega}(\epsilon_2).
$$

For example, if $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$, I can prove the monotonicity of the function $\Psi_{f,\mathbb{R}^n}$ by imposing the following conditions on the Fourier transform $\hat{\phi}$ of the function $\phi$:

- The function $\hat{\phi}$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
- $\hat{\phi}(\xi) < 1 $ for $\||\xi|| \ll 1$
- The function $\hat{\phi}$ is differentiable and for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\xi^\top \hat{\phi}'(\xi) \leq 0.$

Indeed, by Parseval's Theorem
$$
\Psi_{f,\mathbb{R}^n}(\epsilon) = ||\mathcal{F}\left(f - \phi_{\epsilon}*f \right)||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2 = ||\hat{f} - \hat{\phi_\epsilon} \hat{f}||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2 = || (1- \hat{\phi_\epsilon}) \hat{f}||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2
$$
By (*), $ \hat{\phi_\epsilon} = \hat{\phi}(\epsilon \cdot)$, then
$$
\Psi_{f,\mathbb{R}^n}(\epsilon) = || (1- \hat{\phi}(\epsilon \cdot) \hat{f}(\cdot)||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2
$$
Now, since the function $\hat{\phi}$ is bounded and differentiable, the function $\Psi_{f,\mathbb{R}^n}$ is also differentiable and 
$$
\Psi_{f,\mathbb{R}^n}'(\epsilon) = -2 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \xi^\top \hat{\phi}'(\beta \xi)\, (1-\hat{\phi}(\beta \xi) )\,|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 d\xi
$$
Using the second and third condition on the function $\hat{\phi}$, we deduce that $\Psi_{f,\mathbb{R}^n}'(\epsilon) \geq 0$ for small values of $\epsilon$. Whence the monotonicity of the mapping $\Psi_{f,\mathbb{R}^n}$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

Recall that there are functions $\phi$ such that all the conditions stated above are fulfilled. An example is the multivariate Gaussian function 
\begin{equation}
\label{exple phi Multivariate gaussian}
\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(2 \pi \Sigma)}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} x^\top \Sigma^{-1} x \right),
\end{equation}
with a diagonal covariance matrix $\Sigma = diag(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n)$.

Main Problem: How can we ensure monotonicity of $\Psi_{f,\Omega}$ for a subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Please can someone help me ??

Comment: This is quite a good question. At the moment I don't know how to answer it, so let me ask a "counter question": Why do you need this? Do you want to use such a function for proving something else? If so, one can maybe circumvent this. In any case: Good question.

Comment: Yes, I want to use that result to prove something else.

Comment: I want to prove the following claim :

Comment: Claim:
Let $\{\Omega_1, \Omega_2\}$ be a partition of $\mathbb{R}^n$,($\mathbb{R}^n = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$ with $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2 = \emptyset $), $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R} ^n)$ and $\left( \phi_\epsilon \right)_\epsilon$ be an approximation of unity defined as above satisfying the monotonicity of the function $\Psi_{f,\mathbb{R} ^n}$. Then there exists $\rho,\, \delta >0$ such that
$
\forall \,\,\epsilon_1 < \epsilon_2$,  $$ 
\delta ||f - \phi_{\rho \epsilon_1}*f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq ||f - \phi_{\epsilon_1}*f||_{L^2(\Omega_1)} + ||f - \phi_{\epsilon_2}*f||_{L^2(\Omega_2)} 
$$

Comment: Obviously, if the function $\Psi_{f, \Omega_i} $ satisfies the monotonicity for $i=1$ or $i=2$,then the proof of the claim is trivial with $\rho = \delta=1$